# Will Thor lose his powers?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

In *Thor: Ragnarok*, we see that Hela lost her powers or may have been killed after destruction of Asgard as she was getting power from it.

So in the movie, it was mentioned that Thor same as Hela gets his powers from Asgard. Now as Asgard is destroyed, will Thor also lose his powers? Or as Odin said, Asgard is not a place, it is where the people of live. And he will continue to get power from people of Asgard?

Comment: my guess will be no, as it was stated in movie several times, Asgard is not a place but people. Given that, Thor with Loki's help saved Asgardians there is no reason why he should lost his powers.

Comment: I disagree with the assumption that Hela lost her powers, just as any other Asgardian her powers have limits and it seems that Surtr simply overpowered her.

Comment: It was stated in the movie at least twice that Hela's powers originated from Asgard, and that if it were destroyed, she would lose her powers.  However, I don't know if they were being metaphorical or not.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no canon answer to this that I'm aware of - and having one of the main Avengers rendered powerless for the upcoming fight with the biggest, baddest threat they have faced thus far probably isn't an appealing idea to the guys writing *Infinity War*, however the explanation that Asgard is a people not a place seems to provide a decent explanation for him retaining them while staying consistent with his powers being derived from Asgard.

This would also match in with how it works in the comic continuity since

> When Ragnarok occurs there and Asgard is destroyed it is re-established as the floating city of Asgardia. The film strongly hints that the clifftop in Norway will be a "new" Asgard in the MCU

Probably the biggest indication IMO that his powers are intact is:

> That there is no mention of him losing them at the end after the destruction of Asgard when they are traveling on the stolen ship and it sounds like the sort of thing that would come up.

Comment: Since Thor didn't lose his powers, then why Hela did? Do we know?

Comment: There's no evidence one way or the other whether Hela lost her powers - the last we see of her she is fighting Surtur. Whether she is even alive to be de-powered (or not) is unknown.

Comment: And if she does, we could argue that if Asgard is it's people, then taking the people away would be what unpowers her, not the destruction of the city itself.

Comment: As I interpreted it, Hela was unique in that her powers *did* come from the *place* of Asgard.

Comment: May be worth adding that *Infinity War* confirms that Thor didn't lose his powers.

Answer (score 3):

Based strictly on the content from the movie and without delving into the larger MCU, it seemed pretty clear that Asgard (where the power comes from) is the people, not the physical place. Based on this, we have reason to believe that Thor is stronger than ever now that he no longer needs Mjolnir.

There is no evidence that Hela looses her power, it is intimated by Odin that she will be killed in Raganarok, but nothing is said about her power. It seems pretty clear from how she was attacking the demon during the fall of Asgard that she was as powerful as ever, just not powerful enough to survive or win. Based on the cataclysmic destruction of Asgard, it seems a near certainty that Hela is dead, or as dead as anything gets in the MCU.

Comment: Pretty sure there were explicit quotes in the movie from Odin saying that she drew her power from Asgard the place and that the longer she remained there, the stronger she would grow.